# Searching an array with monotonic sequences of values

Tags: arrays, search, sequence, binary-search

I have a large array where the values go monotonically up and down (no ties) in long sub-sequences (such sequences can be any number and of any arbitrarily large size, and of course > 2 terms).

Example in small scale:

**1 2 3 4 5 9** *7 4 3  -2  -5  -7*  **3 5 34 56 67 78 89 90** *8 6 2  -4  -5*   ...

and so on.

I am interested in finding **any** (just **1**, not all) of the values ending an increasing sequence and right where a new decreasing sequence starts.

What is the best way to do this and what is the complexity ?

(My intuitive idea is that this could probably be done similarly to a binary search, so I am guessing an O(logN), not sure however if this might be right)

Comment: By monotonically going up do you mean strictly going up or can entries be repeated like 1, 3, 3, 5? Also, why do you explicitly mention that those subsequences are 'long'? Do you have any heuristics of how often each of them happens for how long? Otherwise this won't make any difference. And in the general case I think you can't avoid a linear running-time to solve this problem.

Comment: Yes, strictly increasing or decreasing and usually very long (eg., several hundred thousand terms, certainly more than 2 terms, no ties).

Answer (score 0):

You cant apply binary search here because given sequence is not sorted.
You can do it in o(n) by searching a first element whose next element is less then that element.
Like in above example 9 will be answer

Comment: My idea was to proceed as follows. Start from the middle. If locally increasing I throw away the left side. If locally decreasing I throw away the right side. Repeat again each time from the middle of the remaining part until I should quickly converge to a "break point". This should be logarithmic, if am not mistaking (let me know if I am)...

Comment: I think your algorithm will work only when the sequence starts with increasing sequence & end with decreasing sequence else not.for example for sequence like 7,8,6,5,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 your algorithm will give answer 11 but answer should  8.

Comment: I agree nikhil. I guess depending on how the sequence is alternating, some adjustments may be needed. (Similar adjustments may be needed if searching a local min.)

Comment: @Pam: Your algo won't work. Consider the sequence ``1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,9`` You would start at 4. It is locally increasing, you throw away the left side, but you won't find the correct result on your right side since it is all increasing. The correct thing would be to return 2 at index 1 (counting from 0). If you reverse the sides to throw away and continue, I simply turn around the example and put the peak at the end.

Comment: Of course it is required each sequence to have at least 2 terms at any time, otherwise you cannot determine the "local monotonicity". I was assuming that implicitly. Clearly if you have single values we cannot even talk of "subsequences",

Comment: @Pam: I'm not getting it. There are always at least 2 terms in any sequence. [1, 2], [2, 1], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]. In that case I don't understand what you mean by "local monotonicity" I guess. And Why are you speaking about single values? Would it be ok if I say the sequence ``1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9``

Comment: I mean that you can say if a subsequence at a given place is going up or down. In order to do that of course you need at least 2 numbers. Say x and y. Depending on their comparison you can say if you are within an increasing piece or not. The sequence you give goes up here: 1 2 3 then it goes down to 2 and then again it goes up. So there is an "isolated" term (2) which is "alone", but we are requiring at least 2 numbers in each subsequence (actually I have very large sequences). In other words, you have up and down but it happens smoothly, with long subsequences each time (not just 1 number).